Check if value exists in multi-select menu
I'm not sure how much of this is Zendesk specific, but I am trying to show/hide customer form fields based on the options chosen in a multi-select field. There isn't a native way of doing it, so I think I have to do it via JavaScript/jQuery.
Here's an obviously not working example of what I'm trying to do:
if( $('.request_custom_fields_19829743171597' contains 'incorrect_party_invite')
$('.request_custom_fields_87493112478139').hide(); 
}

And here's a screenshot of what I believe is the block of code I need to affect in some way.


Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. Please do NOT post pictures of code

You can do something like this since the numbers are likely to change:  const $invite = $('[value= incorrect_party_invite]'); if ($invite.length > 0) $invite.closest('li').hide() for example

Use an attribute selector to look for a descendant element with that specific value, and check the length of the returned jQuery selection. if( $('.request_custom_fields_19829743171597 [value="incorrect_party_invite"]').length)

You can use value attribute equals selector to do this.
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/


if ($(".request_custom_fields_19829743171597[value='incorrect_party_invite']").length) {
  $('.request_custom_fields_87493112478139').hide(); 
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="request_custom_fields_19829743171597" value="incorrect_party_invite"/>
<input type="text" class="request_custom_fields_87493112478139" value="request_custom_fields_87493112478139"/>




This doesn't seem to be doing anything for me.

@Robby Did you tried ?

Yes. When I selected the incorrect_party_invite option in the multi-select, the other field didn't hide.

@Robby the other field class "request_custom_fields_87493112478139" ?

There might be several problems with your code:
1.You want to run the code to get the selected value not as soon as the page loads but in response to a change event in the multiselect field (i.e. when the user selects a value).
Does your code look something like this?
$( ".request_custom_fields_19829743171597" ).on( "change", function() {
  //code to get the value of the multiselect field 
} );

2.Looking at your screenshot, your multiselect doesn't seem to be a standard <select multiple> element but something custom. You might be able to get the selected values using .val() but at the very least you'll get an array of values (documentation here) and you'll have to check if the array contains the string you are looking for.
If getting the selected values with .val() doesn't work, my advice is to check how the html code changes when manually selecting a value. A data attribute or a class might be added, which you can use as a "target" to get the selected value with your code.
3.The custom field ids in your example code and in the screenshot don't correspond. Make sure you're using the right field id/looking at the right field(s). Custom fields ids in Zendesk don't change (except if you delete the field and create a new one of course).
